# Compute time required to travel given distance with constant acceleration and known initial speed

Tags: mathematical-physics

What informations I have:

- Distance to travel
- Initial speed
- Acceleration (constant)

What I need:

- Time it will take to travel that distance in the given conditions.

What would be the formula that gives me that?

If [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/504494/finding-time-with-given-distance-and-acceleration-help-needed) is correct, the formula for an initial speed of $0$ is:

$$\text{time} = \sqrt{\frac{2 \cdot \text{distance}}{\text{acceleration}}}$$

I can't determine the equivalent with a non-null initial speed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The formula $d = v_0t+(at^2/2)$ is what you want. The variable $v_0$ is the initial speed.

Use the quadratic formula to solve for $t$.

Comment: Thank you. How is it that it gives me 2 values then? Do I need to discard the negative one automatically?

Comment: If one solution doesn't make sense physically, discard it.